# Google+ API - Cannot Sign-In - App not registered

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to log in trough Google+ API but when the login popups open I get

> "Android App Not Registered, registering trough Google Console will
>   hide this message"

Now I did register my app and I got an API key and added it to my manifest file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx"/>
```

Then I configured the API Client like this :

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN), new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, manager)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
```

**EDIT:** I also created the `google-services.json` file and put it inside `app/` folder in the project.
It logs me in correctly because I can see the username, email and other information but my app isn't shown between the authorized apps in my account.

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks for your help!!

**EDIT - SOLVED**:

I was using

```
.requestEmail()
```

in the GoogleSignInOptions, while I had to replace it with

```
.requestIdToken([oAuth2 Token])
```

Now the app gets correctly connected with the Google Console and I'm not getting the "App not registered" error anymore!

Comment: Have you added your google account to the set of test accounts?

Comment: Are you testing with a release build or a debug build? Have you registered the fingerprints of *both* signing keys?

Comment: Also, I've noticed that tour APP_ID has this format:

android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx"/>

But you only need to specify the numeric value

Comment: @Tanis.7x I've tried with both release and debug build.

Comment: @LucaMarzi I've created the oAuth2 key and downloaded a client_id.json file but I don't know what to do with it. Also it's the API_KEY not APP_ID in the Manifest

Comment: @LucaDeNardi for the Google Games it's APP_ID in the manifest, something like this:

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
         android:value="@string/app_id"/>`

I've never used Google+ Api but I think it should be the same

Also, do you specify in the manifest the version of the API you're using?

Comment: @LucaMarzi yes I'm specifying the API version..

Comment: Could you post a complete log of the error?

Comment: @LucaMarzi I don't get any error, it just says that my app isn't registered in the Google Console. It looks like I miss something to make the app recognize the one I've set up in the console

Comment: Which fingerprint did you use for the app registration? The debug one? 
You should verify the the app is built with the same fingerprint you have given to Google. By default the builder uses the debug fingerprint and this could be the problem.

Comment: I solved it, check question edits!

Comment: Add the answer as an official answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, check the GoogleSignInOptions.
You should request the token obtained when registering the oAuth2 credentials

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken([oAuth2 Token])
        .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN), new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
        .build();
```